# Support for multiple devices in rxandroidble?

Tags: rxandroidble

If I have multiple, identical, but uniquely named BLE peripheral devices, can this library be made to support that?

So, for example if the peripheral devices were heart rate monitors for a basketball team, could this code be used to support multiple connections to each of those 5 devices concurrently then somehow toggle in between devices to get/send data?

Comment: Yes it can. It is possible. If you have a specific question please add more information and the code that you have tried.

Comment: Thank you. Haven't attempted yet but that is the plan now that you have confirmed it can be made to do so.